# Value of paper-tags-dropdown

Tags: polymer, frontend

This is kind of absurd, but I simply cannot find anywhere how to retrieve the selected tags from the custom polymer element [paper-tags-dropdown](http://polymerel.github.io/paper-tags/components/paper-tags/#paper-tags)

What am I missing? I've spent an hour on this, I cannot find anything using Google. I find it really hard to believe that this is simply skipped in the Docs.

Answer (score 1):

Finally figured it out myself. I added an on-iron-select event to the paper-tags-dropdown element, and in the event handler I can use e.target.selectedItems, where e is the event. This way I can store the selectedItems for later use, when submitting my form. However, I would have liked to be able to do this only at the end, when I am submitting my form. I guess this will do for now.

Comment: However, now I am trying to populate the tags selector with whatever tags I saved, and that is the same headache.